# The 3rd de Rham cohomology of a 6th-dimensional oriented compact smooth manifold has even dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I'm trying to show that

> > Given an oriented compact smooth manifold M of dimension 6, $H^3_{dR}(M)$ has even dimension.

I'm not sure where to begin. Any hint or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cryptic Hint: Hodge star.

Comment: Thanks but would you mind explaining a bit more? I'm not quite familiar with Hodge star operator

Answer (score 3):

The cup product $H^3(M,\Bbb R)\times H^3(M,\Bbb R)\to H^6(M,\Bbb R)\cong\Bbb R$
is a skew-symmetric form. It is also non-degenerate, essentially by Poincare
duality. So $H^3(M,\Bbb R)$ is even-dimensional.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's clear but why is the form non-degenerate by Poincare duality?

Comment: See for instance, chapter 13 of Madsen and Tornehave. @S_j

Answer (score 3):

Equip $M$ with a Riemannian metric $g$.  Then $H^3_{dR}(M;\mathbb{R})$ can be identified with the space $\mathcal{H}^3(M,g)$ of real harmonic $3$-forms on $(M,g)$.  But harmonic iff closed and coclosed, so the Hodge star $\star$ restricts to an endomorphism of $\mathcal{H}^3(M,g)$.  Now the Hodge star on 3-forms in 6-dimension satisfies $\star^2=(-1)^{3(6-3)}=-1$, so $\dim_\mathbb{R}\mathcal{H}^3(M,g)$ is even.